# What do chthonian planets look like?

Tags: planet, exoplanet, planetary-formation, planetary-science

Obviously, a [chthonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chthonian_planet) is going to be *hot,* but what colours could it have? What would the surface composition be? Would it keep patterns from the gas-bands it used to have, or would those have been far too high up for most of its life to leave a mark?

Comment: It would look like rock, not like gas. The gas doesn't leave visible traces, except by maybe changing the surface chemistry. But the overall composition and mineralogy of the surface depends on too many unknown variables and possibly unknown unknowns, so this is really impossible to say.